# Postgres JDBC: Especific error code of PSQLException?

Tags: java, postgresql, exception, jdbc, error-handling

When writing java code that uses an Oracle database, one can always catch `SQLException` an read an specific Oracle error with `e.getErrorCode()`. For example, error 28001 means expired password, 28000 is blocked account, 1017 is wrong user/passsword, etc.

That way I can manage different errors the appropiate way.

But with PostgreSQL databases `e.getErrorCode()` always returns 0, even when catching Postgres-specific `PSQLException`.

**The Question**

- Is there a way that I don't know of to get an specific error code for a Postgres database exception in Java **other than** trying to parse the error message (which by the way could be in any localized language)?

Comment: Have you tried looking at [getSqlState()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html#getSQLState--) instead? See also: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/errcodes-appendix.html

Comment: Just discovered that, please write an answer to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried looking at [getSqlState()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html#getSQLState--) instead? See also: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/errcodes-appendix.html

Comment: Every failed connection attempt returns "08001" regardless of the reason (bad password, bad IP, bad port, bad user, bad database name, no network conecction), everything returns "08001".